# Graph an equation!

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Please note that this question is different from [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/implement-a-graphing-calculator). This one asks for graphical output, while the other one asks for ascii art.

## Objective

Help! Timmy's graphing calculator broke! His calculator cannot graph anymore. However, he has found a way to add new programs and functions to his calculator. Your job is to write a program/function that graphs equations.

## Rules

- Your program/function should take in a string in the form of `"y = random equation involving x"` and graph it on the coordinate grid.
- Timmy's calculator doesn't have that much memory, so please try to make your code as short as possible.
- The operations needed are addition (`+`), subtraction (`-`), multiplication (`*`), division (`/`), exponentiation(`^`) and grouping(`()`)
- Your program/function should be able to graph from `x=-5` to `x=5`, and from `y=-5` to `y=5`.
- Color, axis labels, the grid, numbers, scale, and animation are optional.
- The minimum size of the image should be 50x50 pixels.

## Test Cases

#### Input

`y = x ^ 2`

#### Output

[image: A graph of y=x^2]

#### Input

`y = 4 * x + 3`

#### Output

[image: A graph of y=4x+3]

[Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

You may change the operators, but it adds +10% to your byte count.

Comment: What is the minimum size of the image to be output?

Comment: 50x50 pixels minimum.

Comment: do you need anti-aliasing?

Comment: can we also represent operators as other characters (exponential as `**`)?

Comment: anti-aliasing is optional

Comment: Please try to stick to the operators listed above. If you want to change the operators, it is a +10% byte count.

Comment: Can it take only the `x^2` part or do we need `y = ..`?

Comment: Desmos, 0 bytes? It *has* been defined as a programming language.

Comment: What does this mean: "Your program/function should be able to graph from x=-5 to x=5, and from y=-5 to y=5"? What should the boundaries be if `y = 0.01*x`? And what about `y = 1000*x`? Snould all boundaries be `[-5, 5][-5, 5]` regardless of what the function is?

Comment: What is the minimum step size for x?

Comment: I think you should ban plotting builtins. Those will lead to answers with just one function call.

Comment: @DenkerAffe, In many languages it's impossible to plot without plotting builtins...

Comment: @ANerd-I This is what I thought when I saw the question >_>

Comment: Boundaries should be `[-5, 5][-5, 5]` at all times. The maximum step size for `x` is `0.1`. Plotting built-ins are allowed because many languages can't plot without them.

Comment: What should be done when `y` results in a complex number?

Comment: You can use a 3d plot, not plot the point at all, or just use undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 35 bytes

```
ezplot(input(''));axis([-5 5 -5 5])
```

Input is a string like `'y=2*x^2'`.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify that the string needs to include the quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>89</s> 77 bytes

```
Plot[ToExpression[#~StringDrop~4],{x,-5,5},PlotRange->{-5,5},AspectRatio->1]&
```

Most of it is just formatting to make it look similar to the examples. Please inform me if something isn't required. Includes axis markers, which aren't explicitly disallowed.

Comment: The question says you do not _need_ the axis markers. But if it reduces the byte count you can probably use them.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 40 * 1.1 = 44

```
K0h)5:p'(-5:.1:5)'XHYXUHUw2$XG-5,5hth1ZG
```

This works in [current version (15.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/15.0.0) of the language. *EDIT (June 15, 2017): You can try it at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=K0h%295%3Ap%27%28-5%3A.1%3A5%29%27XHYXUHUw2%24XG-5%2C5hth1ZG&inputs=%27y+%3D+x.%5E2%2F5+%2B+0.6.%2a%28x-1%29+-+2%2a%28x-1%29.%5E%282%2F3%29%27&version=15.0.0)*

`.*`, `./` and `.^` are for multiplication, division and power (that is, add a dot in front).

The following shows an example result running on Matlab.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [RPL/2](http://www.rpl2.net/) 15*1.1 = 16.5

```
STEQ .5 *S DRAW
```

Timmy must key in the equation in capitals, e.g.'Y = X ^ 3', hence the 10% penalty.

The .5 is just luck: the default box is -10…10 × -10…10 with RPL/2.